# How can I select elements that don't include part of data- attribute value?

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

I try to hide elements that don't contain part of a text in the data attribute.
Here is an example. The expected result should be hiding all elements that don't contain the key similar to "UK"

```
<input type="text" id="step3LRGender" data-country="UK IT">
<input type="text" id="step3LRAge" data-country="PL IT">
$('[data-country*="UK"]').show();
$('[data-country!*="UK"]').hide();
```

Comment: why not use the id?

Comment: Because I will have several different elements (divs, labels, inputs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your code with `:not()` as in `$('input:not([data-country*="UK"])').hide();`

**Demo**

```js
$('input[data-country*="UK"]').show();
$('input:not([data-country*="UK"])').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="step3LRGender" data-country="UK IT">
<input type="text" id="step3LRAge" data-country="PL IT">
```

You can also use the following:

```
$('input,div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('country').indexOf("UK") > -1 ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('input,div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('country').indexOf("UK") > -1 ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="step3LRGender" data-country="UK IT">
<input type="text" id="step3LRAge" data-country="PL IT">

<div data-country="UK IT">UK IT</div>
<div data-country="PL IT">PL IT</div>
```

Comment: The issue is that I need to show and hide different kind of elements not just inputs (sorry for the example only with inputs)

Comment: @CarlosMartins Try run the second demo. You can just add the selectors you want